# how to transform this data

Tags: r, tidyverse

i have a table with patient ID and timepoints, example below

| id | timepoint1 | timepoint2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 | 456 |
| 2 | 567 | 568 |

I want to reorganize data with patient id, sample id, and timepoint as below

| id | sample_id | timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 456 | timepoint1 |
| 2 | 567 | timepoint1 |
| 1 | 456 | timepoint2 |
| 2 | 568 | timepoint2 |

Comment: Install and load the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages then run this: `result <- df %>% pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "timepoint", values_to = "sample_id")` where "df" is the name of your data.